# Get the id attr of an input and store as a variable

Tags: jquery

How do I store the ID as a variable in jQuery from the input being clicked. This is what I got but not sure if this will work.

```
<div class="email_button">
   <input id="button1" value="value" />
   <input id="button2" value="value2" />
   <input id="button3" value="value3" />
   <input id="button4" value="value4" />
</div>
```

This is my jQuery

```
jQuery('.email_button input').click(function(){
var buttonid = jQuery($this('.emailbutton input')).attr('id');
)}
```

then I am going to be passing this ID into some conditional php via ajax

Comment: Did you try running the code though?

Comment: `var buttonid = this.id` would suffice

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Did you make a typo on `value"value"` then copy it a few times? Also `$this('.emailbutton input')` does not make sense in the context of your provided code

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt please do not edit the author's original code

Comment: I have edited the HTML to reflect my typos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your html is invalid. change it to the right class as below:

```
$('.email-button input').click(function (e) {
    var buttonid = e.target.id;
});
```

OR

```
$('.email-button input').click(function (e) {
    var buttonid = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="email-button">
  <input id="button1" value="value" />
  <input id="button2" value="value" />
  <input id="button3" value="value" />
  <input id="button4" value="value" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is better than `this.id` especially if propagation occurred in which case it might get the id wrong

Comment: Why did you add `$(this).attr("id")`... I don't get why people like wrapping things in jQuery only to get a property of them. What you're doing is like `var x = {y:5}; $(x).attr("y")` - sure, it works, but it's also quite pointless.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you havn't seen properly I provided 2 a solutions.

Comment: Right, one of them is wrong (e.target) because it will work incorrectly if the event initially fired inside a sub element (let's say OP adds a span and makes the input an actual button tomorrow). The second one is superfluous.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you mean like this [http://jsfiddle.net/mmqcd8La/](http://jsfiddle.net/mmqcd8La/)? What will go wrong here?

Comment: I mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2Lyam2k0/ since the input ids are all button and the HTML is invalid anyway I assume OP has real buttons and you can have stuff in those.

Comment: Well I understand your point now. thanks for that :) But I can't assume from myself I have to go with the question and whatever is asked. Thanks anyway

Comment: Actually i am just using those three inputs, not those specifically as thats just dummy content for the purpose of this question. But @Think Different - your second answer has worked and is what Ill be using.

Comment: @AlexKnopp swap `$(this).attr("id")` for `this.id`, it is completely pointless to wrap it with a `$().attr`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code

JS

```
$('.email-button input').click(function() {
    var buttonid = this.id;
)};
```

`this.id` will return the id of the clicked element
`.email-button` is the class you used in the html, not `.email_button`

HTML

invalid html `<input id="button1" value"value">` it's probably a typo then copied a few times but you missed the equal sign and closing. Should be

```
<input id="button1" value="value" />
```

FYI, you could use `$(this).attr('id')` to get the id however there is no point in doing so in your case

Answer (score 0):

This will do, actually:

```
jQuery('.email_button input').click(function(){
    var buttonid = $(this).attr('id');
   //$.post blah blah blah
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`

```
jQuery('.email_button input').click(function(){
    var buttonid = this.id    //Or $(this).attr('id');
)}
```

`.attr()` is used to get the attribute and `$(this)` specifies current context i.e button.

Also, close input tags with `value=` : `<input... value="..."/>`

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, i have edited my question to reflect my errors and typos.

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
var id;

$("input").click(function(){
id= $(this).attr("id");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="email-button">
  <input id="button1" value="value" />
  <input id="button2" value="value" />
  <input id="button3" value="value" />
  <input id="button4" value="value" />
</div>
```

`$('.email-button input').on("click",function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
)};`